# Recognize which natural number is missing in variable of dataframe and fill it in

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, data-science

Assume I have a dataframe with two columns, one being a row of natural numbers (that was originally complete and therefore just counting the rows) and the other one containing different text strings. Now imagine I have performed an operation that deletes a few of the rows. What I want to achieve now, is to recognize which rows have been gone and fill them in with a number that replaces the original number and inserts NA for the former text value. I hope it becomes clear when looking at the example. Thanks for any help or tips.

```
    names <- c(1:12)

    posts <- c("blabla", "blubla", "wabaluba", "blap", "blub", "jibberish", "hmmm", "lol", "there", "noowwayy", "inded", "thanks")

    before <- data.frame(names, posts)

    current <- before[-c(4,7),]

    desiredoutcome <- data.frame(c(1:12), c("blabla", "blubla", "wabaluba", NA, "blub", "jibberish", NA, "lol", "there", "noowwayy", "inded", "thanks"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is to use `tidyr::complete`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
current %>%
    mutate(names = factor(names, levels = seq(min(names), max(names)))) %>%
    complete(names)
## A tibble: 12 x 2
#   names posts
#   <fct> <fct>
# 1 1     blabla
# 2 2     blubla
# 3 3     wabaluba
# 4 4     NA
# 5 5     blub
# 6 6     jibberish
# 7 7     NA
# 8 8     lol
# 9 9     there
#10 10    noowwayy
#11 11    inded
#12 12    thanks
```

---

Or a `data.table` "join"-approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(current)[CJ(names = seq(min(names), max(names))), on = "names"]
#    names     posts
#1:     1    blabla
#2:     2    blubla
#3:     3  wabaluba
#4:     4      <NA>
#5:     5      blub
#6:     6 jibberish
#7:     7      <NA>
#8:     8       lol
#9:     9     there
#10:    10  noowwayy
#11:    11     inded
#12:    12    thanks
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, we can create a dataframe with sequence between minimum and maximum value of `names` then do a left join with `current`

```
df1 <- data.frame(names = seq(min(current$names), max(current$names)))
merge(df1, current, all.x = TRUE, by = "names")

#   names     posts
#1      1    blabla
#2      2    blubla
#3      3  wabaluba
#4      4      <NA>
#5      5      blub
#6      6 jibberish
#7      7      <NA>
#8      8       lol
#9      9     there
#10    10  noowwayy
#11    11     inded
#12    12    thanks
```

Using `dplyr`

```
dplyr::left_join(df1, current, by = "names")
```